# Regex for double quotes not at start/end of line or preceding/following a comma

Tags: php, regex

Sample data is:

`"3610212505","3610212505","Jack is 6'2" tall"`

I'm looking to escape the double quote that appears after the 2 in 6'2" with a regex pattern in PHP. This line is part of a larger CSV file that I'm trying to cleanse.

Basically any double quote that isn't:

- At the start of a line
- At the end of the line
- Preceding or following a comma

Comment: Use a csv parser and clean each cell.

Comment: shouldn't you escape the `"` instead of removing it?

Comment: @m42: pointless, since the csv is obviously corrupted by having that `"` inside the `Jack` cell.

Comment: @cmorrissey - You're right, escaping would be better.

Comment: What about if you have a comma in a field, just between two double quotes, like `"This is a sample: \",\".","another field"` ???  (of course, unescaped, not like I have put it to differentiate, as in "The string "," will fail the test","another string")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<!^)(?<!,)"(?!$|,)
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wZ0iA3/9

```
$re = "/(?<!^)(?<!,)\"(?!$|,)/im";
$str = "\"3610212505\",\"3610212505\",\"Jack is 6'2\" tall\"";
$subst = "";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: What does the /im at the end of the $re variable do?

Comment: @wkm `i` is for ignorecase.`m` is for multiline.Not really needed here

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
/"(?!(,|$|\w))/
```

- `(?!(,|$|\w))` Ensures that `"` is not followed by `,` or `$` end of string or `\w`

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/lI7cU3/3)

**Example**

```
preg_replace("/\"(?!(,|$|\\w))/", "", "\"3610212505\",\"3610212505\",\"Jack is 6'2\" tall\"");
=> "3610212505","3610212505","Jack is 6'2 tall"
```